# Referencing fitnesse variables into java code

Tags: java, fitnesse-slim

Is there any way that I can reference the values of variables written in my fitnesse wiki inside my java code?

For example, I want to use the value of a variable `location` that I have written in my fitnesse wiki into my fixture code. Is there any way to do it?

This is my code:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\Users\sseth103\Desktop\Fitnesse2

!define location C:\Users\sseth103\Desktop\FT



|Fixture|

|number|result?|

|2     |EVEN   |

|1     |EVEN   |

|3     |EVEN   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass them to the fixture using ${variable}. Like this

```
!define myVariable {hello}

|script|myFixture|${myVariable}|
```